# Arangodb: Is it possible to use an existing collection within Foxx

Tags: arangodb, foxx

I am interested in created a FOXX application for Arango - but I want to use a collection I already have and will use in other ways.  From the interface and the documentation it seems that I need to create a new collection.

Is there some work around where I can use an existing collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can, you can skip creation of new collection when adding new fox service.

And then use any collection in your DB, For instance

```
var db = require('org/arangodb').db;
db.yourcollectionname.save({yourdocument});
```

Here you can find collection methods
https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/develop/javascript-api/@arangodb/collection-object/#documents